# Recursively load from cPickle and create variables to store them

Tags: python, variable-names

I have 26 `.pkl` files at hand, from `dict_a.pkl` to `dict_z.pkl`. I want to load them into the memory, so I can compare elements start with a with variable loaded from `dict_a.pkl`. The reason I want to do this is that each file is really large, if I put them all in one big file, it will be too large to digest. If I load files in an ad hoc style, then it would constantly read disk.

```
import string
alphabet = string.lowercase

for alpha in alphabet:
   ff = 'dict_'+alpha+'.pkl'
   with open(ff, 'r') as tt:
       temp = cPickle.load(tt)
```

How can I replace `temp` variable with `dict_a`, `dict_b` in the loop, so I after the loop, I can directly use the variable `dict_a` to `dict_z`.

Comment: You could have a `dict` of keys `'dict_a'`, `dict_b`, ... with the corresponding values being the pickle objects

Comment: One trick you might like: you can save multiple pickles to a single file then load them one by one.  You don't need 26 files.

Comment: Thanks, @bernie. My pickled stuffs are list with more than one dimension. When indexing them, the code would be so unreadable. I will try to figure out some other way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the glob module to load the pickled files and then work on them one by one.

```
    import glob
    import cPickle as pickle
    picklefiles = glob.glob('*.pkl')
    for pklfile in picklefiles:
       with open(pklfile,'rb') as f:
           pklfile = pickle.load(f)
```

Now you have 26 dictionaries with their corresponding file names.

Edit : you're right @Sean i messed up the third line it should be picklefiles instead of pklfiles. I've updated the code snippet

Edit 2: picklefiles is a list containing all the file names with .pkl extension. In this case

```
picklefiles = [  'dict_a.pkl', 'dict_b.pkl', ........ 'dict_z.pkl' ]
```

In the for loop i'm opening each file and loading the dictionary into a dictionary with the corresponding file name.

Ex :

( this is a variable of type dictionary ) dict_a.pkl = { values from dict_a.pkl }

Comment: I try to run your code. The third line should be ('*.pkl'), if I am correct.

Comment: I try to run your code. The third line should be ('*.pkl'), if I am correct. `pklfiles` is just a list containing all the file names of pkl files, like `dict_x.pkl`. From the code, I suppose it will output variables like `dict_x.pkl`. But this definitely is not a variable name. After running the code, i only got `pklfile` as a variable containing the content of the last pkl file.

Comment: Maybe I didn't run it right, after running the code, I only got one variable `pklfile` containing the content of the last pkl file.

Comment: the third line should be `picklefiles = glob.glob('*.pkl')`. And the result is `picklefiles`, right?

Comment: So, actually in `for` loop. You use pickled file to replace the original string in picklefiles?

Comment: @Sean I didn't know i had enough rights to add comments. LOL.  Check edit 2.

Comment: I try to print picklefiles, the result is `['list_x.pkl', 'list_y.pkl']`. Oh, I forgot to mention, I only use two files as toy.

Comment: @luzlage also when to print `list_x.pkl` or `list_x`, the error says it is not defined. I understand the code and your comment, but still it is not quite right.